# Shiny R: Update a textInput when a pattern matches a given character vector in a data frame

Tags: r, shiny, dplyr

My problem is that I have a given data frame and I have to search for different patterns. When the pattern matches the given character vector the content of the same row, but of a different column should update a textInput.

I created a little shiny app as an example, because my original code is too big. The example works, but I'm using for loops and I don't want to do this. Do anyone know a better solution? Is there a solution with a vectorised function? I really would appreciate if someone knows a dplyr solution.

Example:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
textInput(inputId="wave1", label="wavelength"),
textInput(inputId="wave2", label="wavelength")
)

server <- name <- function(input,output,session) {

df <- data.frame("color" = c("red","blue","green"), "wavelength" = c("700 nm","460 nm","520 nm"))

for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
if(grepl("lue",df$color[i],fixed=TRUE) == TRUE){updateTextInput(session, inputId="wave1", label = NULL, value = df$wavelength[i],placeholder = NULL)}
}

for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
if(grepl("ee",df$color[i],fixed=TRUE) == TRUE){updateTextInput(session, inputId="wave2", label = NULL, value = df$wavelength[i],placeholder = NULL)}
}
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of looping, you can index the dataframe directly from the result of grep:

```
server <- name <- function(input,output,session) {

    df <- data.frame("color" = c("red","blue","green"), "wavelength" = c("700 nm","460 nm","520 nm"))

    updateTextInput(session, inputId="wave1", label = NULL,
                    value = df$wavelength[grep("lue", df$color, fixed=TRUE)],
                    placeholder = NULL)
    updateTextInput(session, inputId="wave2", label = NULL,
                    value = df$wavelength[grep("ee", df$color, fixed=TRUE)],
                    placeholder = NULL)
}
```

And one way to do this using `dplyr` is:

```
server <- name <- function(input,output,session) {

    df <- data.frame("color" = c("red","blue","green"), "wavelength" = c("700 nm","460 nm","520 nm"))

    updateTextInput(session, inputId="wave1", label = NULL,
                    value = dplyr::filter(df, grepl("lue", color, fixed=TRUE)) %>% dplyr::pull(wavelength),
                    placeholder = NULL)
    updateTextInput(session, inputId="wave2", label = NULL,
                    value = dplyr::filter(df, grepl("ee", color, fixed=TRUE)) %>% dplyr::pull(wavelength),
                    placeholder = NULL)
}
```

Comment: I think hes looking for some sort of autocomplete where the color names will translate into the wavelength, so there needs to be a listener